# snprintf() only reads until new line character?

Tags: c, newline

I'd like to send a message over a socket that looks like so: "USER anonymous\r\n". 
In order to create a formatted string instead of a constant string, I used snprintf(). Unfortunately, it does not seem to copy the newline character `\n`, but just the carriage return `\r`.

```
#define USERNAME_ANONYMOUS "anonymous"
[...]


// Inside a function.
int sz = snprintf(NULL, 0, "USER %s\r\n", USERNAME_ANONYMOUS);
char* username = NULL;
if ((username = calloc(sz + 1, sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
    perror("Could not allocate memory");
    return;
}
snprintf(username, sz, "USER %s\r\n", USERNAME_ANONYMOUS);
for (int i = 0; i <= sz; i++) {
    printf("%c  %d\n", username[i], username[i]);
}
```

The output:

```
U  85
S  83
E  69
R  82
   32
a  97
n  110
o  111
n  110
y  121
m  109
o  111
u  117
s  115
  13
  0
  0
```

Comment: Because this is only a part of a project. The piece of code is inside a function. I didn't want to post the whole code because it would be too big.

Comment: Which means the code you post should not compile?

Comment: I thought the part I posted wouldn't be too hard to understand and would be easy to copy and paste to try it out. There was no bad intention or so behind it... I will edit it, don't worry, I just haven't thought about that.

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this `snprintf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

> At most bufsz - 1 characters are written.

The size you provide must be *including* the terminator. You need to use `sz + 1` to print the full string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you allocate a buffer of size `sz + 1` then pass *that buffer size* to the second `snprintf` call, which is `sz + 1` and not `sz`, which is the number you pass.

The second call to `snprintf` should read:

```
snprintf(username, sz + 1, "USER %s\r\n", USERNAME_ANONYMOUS);
```

or it will overwrite the last `\n` with the null terminator, because it has not enough space for the whole string you want to print.